# another sed question

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a daily CSV export of files of about 200-50 Gb per/day. Each CSV file's first field is a date information like that. Each CSV file has 22 fields

```
/data/exported$ head  0000_processmessages_export_20170509_000144.csv | awk -F ";" '{print $1}'
2017-05-08T21:59:10.263Z
2017-05-08T21:59:10.000Z
2017-05-08T21:59:10.000Z
2017-05-08T18:59:11.000Z
2017-05-08T18:59:11.000Z
2017-05-08T21:00:00.000Z
2017-05-08T21:00:00.000Z
2017-05-08T21:00:00.000Z
2017-05-08T21:00:00.000Z
2017-05-08T21:00:00.000Z
```

So basically I want to add 2 more fields (Field22 and Field23) to the end of each row in a csv file and these fields like YYYYDDMMHH and YYYYMMDD format and I must extract them from the first field in row.  So

```
Field 23    Field 24 
2017050821  20170508
2017050821  20170508
2017050821  20170508
2017050818  20170508
2017050818  20170508
2017050821  20170508
2017050821  20170508
2017050821  20170508
2017050821  20170508
2017050821  20170508
```

How can I do that with sed and/or bash commands?

Comment: Why don't you simplify your task? Is the question about dates conversions or about adding columns? Why don't you use `awk`, not sed? I think `awk` may be better with this.

Comment: Please clarify your question and its title. Please use an informative title.

Comment: By the way, why do you want to add these fields? What is your task?

Comment: Could I ask for a better title than "another sed question"? Maybe ask for what you're trying to do, instead.

Comment: if possible, consider having one column with unix timestamp instead of 3 fields

Comment: The purpose of a CSV file is to contain related, tabular data. It is wise to minimize data where possible. It doesn't make sense to have data in fields that can simply be generated based on data in other fields.

Comment: the title it is too generic, it will not be possible to classify the problem and make the solution not redundant within the community. Please change the title of the question.

Comment: I am sorry for bad title, 

I also tried with awk but it fails  in some very large files, I have not any control for exported files. .

Comment: @YaroslavNikitenko

I will move this files to HDFS and I have a plan to use partition field23 and will use field24 in some queries. I also tried with Pig but I am trying to build fastest solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it seems silly to have redundant information like that. But if you really need to do it, use capture groups and back-references:

```
sed 's/^\(....\)-\(..\)-\(..\)T\(..\).*/&;\1\2\3\4;\1\2\3/'
```

Comment: thx for solution I just replaced your solution with 

    sed 's/^(....)-(..)-(..)T(..):&#‌​40;..):(..&#‌​41;.*/&;\1\2\3\4;\1\‌​2\3/'

Comment: I misread your required output, I thought the first column had the whole time. But you shouldn't have `&#40` in the pattern, that doesn't appear in the original. I've updated the answer I think it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -F\; -pale '$_ .= join ";", q{}, $F[0] =~ tr/T-//dr =~ /^((\d{8})\d{2})/' CSV.file
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input seems to be `;`-delimited, so I'm assuming that you'd like the output to be similarly delimited.

```
$ cat file.csv
2017-05-08T21:59:10.263Z;some;other;fields
2017-05-08T21:59:10.000Z;some;other;fields
2017-05-08T21:59:10.000Z;some;other;fields
2017-05-08T18:59:11.000Z;some;other;fields
2017-05-08T18:59:11.000Z;some;other;fields
2017-05-08T21:00:00.000Z;some;other;fields
2017-05-08T21:00:00.000Z;some;other;fields
2017-05-08T21:00:00.000Z;some;other;fields
2017-05-08T21:00:00.000Z;some;other;fields
2017-05-08T21:00:00.000Z;some;other;fields
```

```
$ awk -F ';' -v OFS=';' '{ split($1,a,":"); gsub("[^0-9]","",a[1]); $(NF+1)=a[1]; $(NF+1)=substr(a[1],0,8); print}' file.csv
2017-05-08T21:59:10.263Z;some;other;fields;2017050821;20170508
2017-05-08T21:59:10.000Z;some;other;fields;2017050821;20170508
2017-05-08T21:59:10.000Z;some;other;fields;2017050821;20170508
2017-05-08T18:59:11.000Z;some;other;fields;2017050818;20170508
2017-05-08T18:59:11.000Z;some;other;fields;2017050818;20170508
2017-05-08T21:00:00.000Z;some;other;fields;2017050821;20170508
2017-05-08T21:00:00.000Z;some;other;fields;2017050821;20170508
2017-05-08T21:00:00.000Z;some;other;fields;2017050821;20170508
2017-05-08T21:00:00.000Z;some;other;fields;2017050821;20170508
2017-05-08T21:00:00.000Z;some;other;fields;2017050821;20170508
```

The `awk` program takes the first `;`-delimited field and splits it on `:`.  It then removes all non-digits from the first part of the field (the bit before the first `:`) and adds it as a new field at the end.  A second new field is then appended to the end of the line, consisting of only the first eight characters of the first new field.  The new line is then printed.